# Reactive array of objects and "Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning Web Components"

Tags: lightning-web-components, object, array, lightning-web-security

I have a component that iterates through a property that is an array of objects.

```html
<template>
  <template for:each={widgets} for:item="widget">
    <p key="widget.name">
      <a onclick={clickedWidget} href="#" data-widget={widget.name}>{widget.name} ({widget.clicked})</a>
    </p>
  </template>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Widgets extends LightningElement {
  widgets = [
    {
      name: 'Widget 1',
      clicked: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Widget 2',
      clicked: false
    }
  ];

  clickedWidget(event) {
    const widget = event.target.dataset.widget;
    const clickedWidget = this.widgets.find(el => el.name === widget); // Does not work!
    clickedWidget.clicked = true;
  }

}
```

Saw [this question and answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/385211/proxy-on-all-objects-and-arrays-logged-in-lwc-salesforce). My package requires **Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning Web Components** to be enabled (one component uses the Carbon Charts library). I don't have the luxury of just turning it off.

New to LWC... should I be doing something differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primitives are reactive, objects are not. However, you can just add `@track` to make an object [reactive](https://lwc.dev/guide/javascript_reactive#track-changes-inside-objects-and-arrays):

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class Widgets extends LightningElement {
  @track widgets = [
    {
      name: 'Widget 1',
      clicked: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Widget 2',
      clicked: false
    }
  ];

  clickedWidget(event) {
    const widget = event.target.dataset.widget;
    const clickedWidget = this.widgets.find(el => el.name === widget);
    clickedWidget.clicked = true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly - thanks! Minor thing... please add "k" to "trac" in the import.

Comment: @nstuyvesant Haha, typos happen to everyone. I've edited it.

Comment: Thanks again! Sorry to be nitpicky. Hoping the problem and answer will help others.